# Tooltip for folders

Tags: javascript, user-interface, treeview, webix

I made the following [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/011efdba) with the datatree:

```
{ 
  view:"tree",
  id:"mytree",
  tooltip:true, 
  data:tree_data,       
  select:true,      
  tooltip:function(){}
}
```

How can I set the tooltip in Webix only for folders? I suspect it can be done with some function,  but actually I can't achieve this.

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution via `isBranch` method:

```
tooltip:function(obj){
  var ids = obj.id;      
  if($$("mytree").isBranch(ids))
    return "Tooltip";
  else
    return '';   
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/6f42af5e

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
webix.ui({   
  cols:[
    { 
      view:"tree",
      id:"mytree",
      tooltip:true, 
      data:tree_data,       
      select:true,      
      tooltip:{
                template:"<span class='webix_strong'>Contenido: </span> #value#<br/>"
            },
    },        
  ]   
});
```

[Look](http://webix.com/snippet/5fdeb907).

Comment: No. This is a pretty simple solution, I've seen it in the related docs. But I need a tooltip for the folders only